# Loading DLL file in java

Tags: java

While loading a dll file, using System.loadLibrary method, in a RCP application, it's working as long as I am launching the application from Eclipse itself. But when exporting the RCP application and launching from the exported code, I am getting this exception :

```
ERROR - Native code library failed to load. See the chapter on Dynamic Linking Problems in the SWIG Java documentation for help. Try using a 32 bit JRE also.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\ExportTest\eclipse\plugins\<application_name>\ext\securityinterfaceX86\SecurityInterface-x86.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Answer (score 6):

You are loading a 32bit C++ binary from a 64 bit JVM. You need to either use a 32 bit JVM or go for a mixed mode JVM. Use the same JRE that your Eclipse uses and you will be fine.

Comment: My system is having 32 bit JDK and JRE and also while loading the dll am checking "System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")" and it's returning 32 only.